# Unable to iterate over tuple list MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have the following code, where I am trying to iterate over a tuple:

```
cust_list = ('138')

for cust in cust_list:
    dbQuery =  """
        SELECT DISTINCT
            c.id,
            c.name,
            c.email
        FROM
            customers c
        WHERE
            c.id = %s;
    """
    cur1.execute(dbQuery, cust)

    row = cur1.fetchone()
    cust_name = row[1]
    cust_email = row[2]
```

The table customers contains a record as follows

```
id: 138
Name: Xoom Support
Email: support@example.com
```

I would expect the for loop to run once for the single value in the tuple, but instead I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "/usr/local/bin/stats-test.py", line 80, in <module>
        cust_name = row[1]
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I have attempted to print the row which yields the following:

```
    (1L, 'Xoom Support', 'support@example.com')
    ^^^
     |
 What is this??
```

I am thoroughly confused as to what is going on.

Comment: Does the error happen in the first execution of the loop? I mean, is the row you have printed the one which generates the error? And the `1L` indicates the number 1 along with the Long type.

Comment: @Javitronxo I thought that was what 1L meant, not sure why I am getting that. The problem seems to be with the single value tuple, if I set the tuple to ('138','123') the loop seems to work OK :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, your confusion with the `1L` made me identify the error. There is a difference iterating over a tuple with just one number, and a tuple with two numbers, and that difference is the absence of the comma. In fact, the type for `cust_list = ('138')` is String.

In the first case you will iterate over each digit of the number, whereas in the second case you will iterate over each number. Check out the following execution:

```
>>> cust_list = ('138')
>>> for cust in cust_list:
...   print cust
...
1
3
8
>>> cust_list = ('138','123')
>>> for cust in cust_list:
...   print cust
...
138
123
```

To write a tuple containing a single value you have to include a comma, even though there is only one value...

Redefine your tuple to obtain the desired execution:

```
>>> cust_list = ('138',)
>>> for cust in cust_list:
...   print cust
...
138
```

Comment: Understood, and thanks for the full explanation. Learnt something about tuples today!